# sqlite- Variable table name does not work with delete or insert command

Tags: python-3.x, variables, sqlite

I use b[0], b[1], ... for table names and check if which table is empty, I want to insert some data into it.

```
b = [f't{i}' for i in range(1,12)]

im.execute("delete from " + b[0] + "")#does not work
im.execute("select no from " + b[1] + "")#this works

if im.fetchone == None:
    im.execute("insert into " + b[1] + " select * from table where no = 
15")#does not work
```

No error message, just does not work. Help please.

Comment: The last one won't work unless there is a table named `table`, which would be a terrible idea. The diff between the 1st and 2nd (array subscript) could be significant to the problem. You won't get an error message from sqlite unless you ask for it (like interrogating the return value of the execute, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply DinoCoderSaurus.  That is solution that I found: Sqlite 3 accepts null, but Python accepts None for empty values. When I assign "None = null" before query,  it works.